# Unwrap uvw box with texture

Tags: texturing, uv, shrinkwrap

I have problem with unwrap of simple box. As shown in picture I uploaded, UV map is in the middle of my texture, but blue parts of texture are visible on my model.

I tried to apply scale, but it didn't help? Why does it seem like my UV is intersecting with blue stripes of my texture?

Comment: You haven't included a picture! [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).